# How can I estimate the instruction count/performance of a DSP algorithm on a specific architecture?

Tags: performance, assembly, arm, signal-processing, benchmarking

I've been asked to provide a reverb algorithm for an audio interface hardware using a 160 MHz ARM processor. It's a fairly lightweight reverb effect written in C. However, my knowledge is a little lacking when it comes to low level architecture and performance testing and measurement.

I need to provide at least some estimates on how it will perform on the device's CPU, as they would like to keep it within 3 - 5%.  So far I've followed these steps, so please let me know if I'm at least on the right track.

I disassembled the .c file containing all the processing of the reverb in Xcode and counted up the number of assembly instructions that are called in the callback function processing the audio.  At 256 samples per block, I'm looking at around 400,000 assembly instructions.

Is there any way to roughly estimate how this algorithm will perform on a 160 MHz ARM processor?  The audio library I'm using for I/O has a measurment for CPU load, and I'm getting between 2 - 3% on my Mac Pro for the callback routine.

Am I going about this the right way?  Any suggestions to provide an estimate on this?
Thanks.

Comment: you dont have any hardware to try it on?  specifically that processor at that speed with similar/same memory/flash?

Comment: Not specifically what I'm building it for, but maybe trying it on my iPhone would give a better estimate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a lot more information about the processors particular implementation of the ARM ISA, than just the MHz.  Factors affecting performance include use of multi-cycle instructions, super-scaler dispatch/retirement capabilities, pipeline interlocks, cache size and policy affecting the hit ratios, memory latencies, etc.  Also how well the compiler you use optimizes for your chosen ARM implementation.

One can easily end up with well over a 10X CPI (cycles-per-instruction) difference in machine code execution between a desktop PC and an embedded RISC CPU, as well as the actual machine code being very different.

It's usually easier to benchmark your code.

Comment: That helps a lot in answering what kind of information I would need to determine performance, or at least make a better estimation. Thanks.

Comment: Once pipelines and caches came into play, execution is much less deterministic (for users without visibility to the guts of the design).  Even with the physical hardware there are many traps you can fall into and have a false sense of performance.  Add an operating system to it and it gets that much worse.